# Quickfixj receive logout immediately when client logon

Tags: quickfixj

I have a bug when connect with my client in quickfixj.
The error message is:

```
11 Jun 2014 07:00:29,370  INFO [SocketAcceptorIoProcessor-0.0] MINA session created: /103.13.177.74:53638
11 Jun 2014 07:00:29,396  INFO [QFJ Message Processor] quickfix.Session - Disconnecting: Session reset
11 Jun 2014 07:00:34,445  INFO [SocketAcceptorIoProcessor-0.0] MINA session created: /103.13.177.74:53639
```

And in event log:

```
20140611-00:00:29.389: Accepting session FIX.4.2:... from /103.13.177.74:53638
20140611-00:00:29.389: Acceptor heartbeat set to 30 seconds
20140611-00:00:34.446: Accepting session FIX.4.2:... from /103.13.177.74:53639
20140611-00:00:34.446: Acceptor heartbeat set to 30 seconds
```

I use quickfixj 1.5.1.

More about Error message:

```
11 Jun 2014 07:00:34,447  WARN [QFJ Message Processor]  fromAdmin.:Logon.:TargetNum= 3
11 Jun 2014 07:00:34,451  INFO [QFJ Message Processor]  Session Logon.: FIX.4.2:
11 Jun 2014 07:00:34,451  INFO [QFJ Message Processor] Session Logon.:ExpectedSenderNum= 3
11 Jun 2014 07:00:34,451  INFO [QFJ Message Processor] Session Logon.:ExpectedTargetNum= 1
11 Jun 2014 07:00:34,475  WARN [QFJ Message Processor] fromAdmin.:Logout.:TargetNum= 4.:Text=Catastrophic Error: Incoming sequence number (1) is less than expected (2) without PossDupFlag being set.  Logging out.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickfixj 1.5.1 have some bug with logon and StartTime configuration. 
You should try to upgrade to newest version of quickfixj (1.5.3)
See more here: http://www.quickfixj.org/jira/browse/QFJ-357

Answer (score 1):

You should check start time and endtime in quickfix cfg file.

And try to add CheckLatency flag

See more in: http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.0/usage/configuration.html